# View an record values of properties without debugging

Tags: .net, debugging

Is there a lightweight way to watch and record the values of properties of arbitary instances in my .NET application? Preferably one that works for release builds too and without having to attach a full fledged debugger. Sort of like what [Crack.NET](http://cracknetproject.codeplex.com/releases/view/19002) does but with live updates, recording and most importantly, one that works with mixed mode (MFC, C++/CLI) assemblies too.

Answer (score 1):

Snoop.NET and [Hawkeye](http://www.acorns.com.au/Projects/Hawkeye/) update their properties on the fly, but have no recording feature.

They're both open source, so I guess you could add that feature by yourself, but assuming you're only doing this for debugging/learning needs, I'd suggest just opening Snoop/Hawkeye and using a video recording tool like SnagIt to capture a video of both the application I'm learning about, and the properties window as it refreshes.

Comment: Both tools only work for GUI Controls. Unlike Crack.NET where I can investigate all type instances in a process.